# RequireJS - Working with 2 jQuery libs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd

In a project I am maintaining, I am forced to stick with 2 jQuery lib calls in one page (for now at least):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> /* 1st jQuery call */
<script>
    /* Section A - Some code that uses jQuery */
</script>

<script data-main="main" src="require.min.js">
     /* 2nd jQuery call made inside */
</script>

<script>
    /* Section B - Some code that uses jQuery */
</script>
```

This has been causing some weirdness in Section B that I've verified the source of the issue being the repeated inclusion of the jQuery lib.

Suppose I only have control over the AMD section - what's the best/recommended option(s) I've got to handle this situation? Thanks!

Comment: explain more **require.min.js**, is this another jquery plugin like the above one: **1.8.3/jquery.min.js**? if yes what version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery *is* an AMD module. Not only that, it's a *named* AMD module, which makes it super difficult to use 2 versions of jQuery on the same page. (see this http://dvdotsenko.blogspot.com/2011/12/amd-modules-with-named-defines-so-much.html)

However, in your case you don't need 2 different *versions* of jQuery. You just need to use jQuery once outside of AMD and then inside of AMD code tree.

Your solution is very simple: load require.js *BEFORE* you load jQuery. (Translation: put the script tag that loads RequireJS before the script tag that loads jQuery.

```
<script src="require.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    /* Section A - Some code that uses gloabl jQuery */
</script>
<script>
    // start the AMD code tree
    require(['main'],function(main){
        // run code that main module returns.
        // Don't know what that may mean in your case.
        // example:
        main()
    })
</script>
```

What happens there:

1. requirejs loads and sets up global `require` and `define` objects
2. jQuery loads and it (a) always sets global window.jQuery (+ window.$) and (b) if `define` exists and it's of AMD variety, it defines itself as named module with specific name - "jquery" <- exactly that.
3. Your code depending on global jQuery runs.
4. Your code depending on AMD-registered jQuery runs.

3 and 4 use one and the same exact instance of jQuery.

You absolutely must require jQuery as "jquery" No other string will give you a jQuery instance.

The only way you can alias jQuery is by creating a separate named define that repackages already-defined 'jquery' module:

```
define(
  'my_jquery_yey'
  , ['jquery']
  , function($){return $}
)
```

Comment: Out-of-the-box awesome thinking and simple solution, I salute you sir! =D

Answer (score 0):

If you intent to use requireJs, load both versions of jQuery with requireJs, so

- need to load at least one of the code blocks with [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/),
- use the shim property in the require.config object.

**Config (main.js):**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jqueryV1: "path/to/jqueryV1",
        jqueryV2: "path/to/jqueryV2"
    },
    shim: {
        jqueryV1: {
          exports: 'jQuery',
          init: function() {
             return this.jQuery.noConflict();
          }
       },
       jqueryV2: {
          exports: 'jQuery',
          init: function() {
             return this.jQuery.noConflict();
          }
       }
    } 
});
```

Defining modules should be easy now.

**Section A**

```
define(['jqueryV1'], function($) {
   // jQuery code section A
});
```

**Section B**

```
define(['jqueryV2'], function($) {
   // jQuery code section B
});
```

Comment: The main issue is that I am stuck with one script loading AND one AMD loading for now, or it would be quite easy to solve =(

Comment: Just remove the script tag referring to jquery and replace it with a path in require.config -> jqueryV1 : 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min'

Comment: jQuery *IS* an AMD module by default. It was an AMD module for the last 2 years or so. If you use standard jQuery (from CDN for example) it has **named** define() in the end. Requiring jQuery by any name other than "jquery" (note capitalization and contents must be exactly that) will return undefined to you.