# Loading Dynamic Require.js modules

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

Have spent the whole day on this and i think its time for a shout out. I am using require.js to include modules in my backbone app. This is what i have:

My requirejs config:

```
paths:
 jquery: "backbone/initializers/jquery_loader"
 jqueryui: "backbone/initializers/jqueryui_loader"   
modules:
 - name: 'application'
 - name: 'jquery'
  exclude: ['application']
 - name: 'jqueryui'
  exclude: ['application', 'jquery']
 - name: 'email'
  exclude: ['application']
 - name: 'department_home'
  exclude: ['application']
priority: ['application', 'jquery', 'jqueryui']
```

My jquery_loader:

```
define ["jquery.min"], () ->
 jQuery = $
 jQuery.noConflict(true)
```

My jqueryui_loader:

```
define ['jquery.ui.all'], () ->
```

My email module:

```
define ['marionette', 'jqueryui', 'tags'], (Marionette, ui, tags) ->
```

My department home module

```
define ['marionette', 'jqueryui', 'dept_tags'], (Marionette, ui, tags) ->
```

Everything works as expected and compiles, but maybe i don't understand it or i am missing something, the email module is loaded dynamically on a click event, and it has jqueryui included in it, which i believe is just an r.js optimized file.

Now i do another click event after email module is loaded, and i see that the department module also has jquerui in it, both come in at 90KB, what i expected is for department module to use the jqueryui thats already loaded by the email module.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use jquery loader like this. You should use the shim property to initialize the noConflict. [I've answered something similar a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14034840/1916258).

In your case it would be something like this (but in coffeescript then):

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: "path/to/jquery",
        jqueryui: "path/to/jqueryui"
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
          exports: 'jQuery',
          init: function() {
             return this.jQuery.noConflict();
          },
        jqueryui: {
          deps: ['jquery']
       }
    } 
});
```