# Best Practices to add 3rd party jQuery plugins to requireJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

Say for example, someone wrote a great jQuery plugin that I want to use on my site, but it's non-AMD. How do I add it to requireJS? For demo purposes, pretend this plugin is called "codeFormatter" and it takes any `<pre>` tag and formats it such that each line gets indices. And obviously, codeformatter need jQuery to work.

Let's say before adding codeFormatter, there's a `<pre>` section on my page that looks like this:

```
var foo = function() {
    console.log("foo");
}
```

And let's say this jQuery codeformatter is called and fired (traditionally) via:

```
<script src="scripts/lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/codeformatter.js"></script>
<script>
    $("pre").codeFormatter();
</script>
```

After adding codeFormatter:

```
1. var foo = function() {
2.     console.log("foo");
3. }
```

Anyway, since this codeFormatter.js plugin is maintained by someone else remotely, such as being stored on github, there's no point in me copying the code and then using the `define()` method.

What is the best practice for putting codeFormatter.js into requireJS with shim or define or require, etc?

Comment: I would modify the plugin to be AMD, if allowed by the licensing of course. Really shouldn't be hotlinking to things other than on CDN's anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is a very common one, which is why the RequireJS docs outline jQuery plugins in more detail. Read the `shim` config option in more detail - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Answer (score 0):

If plugins are small in size, recommend to concatenate several plugins into one JS file and load after jQuery.

If the plugins are large files (jquery-ui for example) and I don't want to concat them or want to pull them from CDN I routinely roll a named define like so:

```
<script src="path/to/amd_loader.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

define(
    'jqueryplugins'
    , [
        'jquery'
        , 'js!plain/js/fileA.js' // loading through "js" plugin
        , 'actually/an/amd/compatible/module'
        , 'js!plain/js/fileB.js' // loading through "js" plugin
    ]
    // because plugins AUGMENT $, no point returning them separately
    // just return back the augmented jQuery reference.
    , function($){return $} 
)

</script>
...
<script>

require(
    ['jqueryplugins', 'path/to/mycode']
    , function($, mycode){
        mycode($)
    }
)

</script>
```

Note, while jQuery is an AMD module I don't bother with initial fetch for it through AMD loader. It registers itself as named module and I just consume it later.(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298476/366864) This removes the need for complicated `shim` and `path` configs. If you don't order the preload of jQuery by hand, you will have to deal with need to order jquery load before plugins though other means.